# Zend Framework is it worth it?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am building an application using the Zend Framework and I wonder if this framework is a bit too bloated or over done. Maybe its the way I am tackling the problem but I see that using this framework forces me to write so much more code.

Any suggestions or advice?

Comment: What are you trying to build?

Comment: a ticketing system, and a cms

Comment: check out redmine.  it has issue management, svn integration, and a wiki.  you can get an "installable" from bitnami.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZF components are excellent for targeted tasks - e.g. Zend_Oauth, Zend_Pdf, Zend_Gdata, etc. You can use them for achieving these tasks even while not basing your application on ZF MVC structure, and I definitely advise you to do so (disclaimer: I am a contributor to ZF so I can be subjective).

As for the big ZF stuff like Zend_Application, Zend_View, etc. - that depends on your need and style. For a big project, I'd say go for it, it may seem big in the beginning but you'll end up with something roughly that big in any case.

If, on the other hand, you have a smaller project, then you may consider using something simple or maybe no framework at all - but beware, some small projects grow big faster than you expect.

Looking at your comment that you are building ticketing system and CMS, it looks like it's big enough for a framework. Give ZF a try. Start with smaller, simpler examples, using a good book and some example code may be very helpful too. When you get into the mindset you'll discover it's not actually as bloated as you thought - it just has more functionality and extension points, but you will discover you may need that functionality down the road.

Answer (score 3):

1. Are you sure you need your own CMS? Will you write a good anti spam filter? It is not ZF forcing you to write more code. Maybe you just have chosen wrong path.

Consider integrating your app with some good solutions like Wordpress or Drupal.

1. Zend Framework is not bloated. In fact, it is an example of good programming practices. It is mature, and this means it should be used for mature projects and by mature programmers.

Altought ZF is the best one here, you may try Symfony, maybe you may find it more friendly. There are a lot of user contributed, ready resources.

Answer (score 1):

this is only suggestions or advice, so insert disclaimer here.

it is not how much code you have to write to show the first page in your application.  it is how much code in total is going to be there in your application when you finish, and how much of it is going to be repeated all over the place. and how easy it is going to be to make changes/maintain.

with zend you write more code now so that you write less code later.  at the start you are writing controllers, models, mappers, views, forms and layouts.  pretty soon you will be adding actions to controllers, writing forms and views only.

the cost of writing a model should not be allocated to the first view you write.  allocate it over the add, edit, delete and list views, as well as the search views.

i am only 4 weeks into zend framework and so i consider myself a beginner in it, but i have been programming for 25 years, and php for 6 years, so i see the wisdom.

the things that you might need to be aware of are that some zend routines dont work in php 5.3, i dont know any more about that.

edit:  if you are looking for simpler frameworks, try codeigniter (or kohana which is a fork of codeigniter).  it is simpler to use because you manually add files, instead of running a script to generate controllers, models, etc. (like with symfony, zend, cakephp, yii etc).  most of the work i have done so far has been with codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are expecting to develop faster with typing less, Zend Framework may not the best choice. It definitely takes more time typing, things like `$this->getRouter()->getWhatever()->thenSmtMore()->theFuncNeeded()`. However it's well structured and nicely engineered. And what Sasha Shumann said in a QA meeting is, "you spend more time on reading the code than writing it". Well, it makes sense when you think that way but in real life, especially if you are working on bunch of low-budget projects where you can sacrifice quality a bit, Zend Framework's default application infrastructure can slow you down. But this doesn't mean that ZF is bloated...

The thing that I love about ZF is, as the modules are loosely coupled, you always have the chance of using it as a library or develop your own working environment based on ZF components. And that's exactly what I've done, so I spent a few months on building up my own kind of framework based on ZF components and I can build new projects faster, the way I like.

In my experience, when you use any framework, including Ruby on Rails or Django, yes you gain lot's of speed at the beginning but when you encounter special cases, it gets harder to find the proper solution for that case. The solution is to spend enough time for mastering the framework, definitely get some community support as the standard documentation is never enough, and optimize your work flow (like creating your code snippets library, using an advanced IDE like netbeans or Zend Studio, using code templates etc.)